# What is the meaning of "we take the sword to "?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

A: Are we dependent on that for anything?

B:  I don't actually know for sure

B:  Tom / Ben would be the best bet here.

B:  **My feeling is that we take the sword to this if we can**

What is the meaning of the last sentence? I am curious about "**take the sword to"**.

Comment: Could you narrow down the context or add a source? A rough guess would be to slice in two or destroy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Take the sword to** (or *take a sword to*, *take an axe to*, *put it to the axe*) means to get rid of something or destroy it.

"A" asks *do we need this for anything?* and "B" says *I don't know, but I feel we should get rid of it.*

The use is causal and might refer to (for example) taking code out of a program or deleting scenes from a story or removing dishes from a dinner plan. It rarely means destroying physical objects.